# DIV positioning problem on IE

Tags: css

i have a problem for my layout... it should be simple but i just won't get it right.
It works on firefox but not on IE .... :'(

Problem:
the div leftBar and rightBar should be resizing to the content. If there is a lot of text, they should have the same height (therefor i used top and bottom on an absolute positioning) the content is all right and it works just the leftBar and the rightBar won't resize... thx for responding,
regards marius

```
<div id="container" style="position:relative; width:100px;">
  <div id="leftBar" style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; bottom:0px; width:10px;"></div>
  <div id="content" style="position:relative; margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px;"></div>
  <div id="rightBar" style="position:absolute; right:0; top:0; bottom:0px; width:10px;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to have height as auto `style="height: auto;"`

Answer (score 0):

**3 column liquid layout**: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm